# Create JSON object from HTML using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want to create JSON Object using JQuery. I've written JQuery code, but it is not working expected. Here I've added my JQuery code in StackExchange.

HTML:

```
<div id="addconfigurations">
    <div class="action DummyAction2" id="10">
        <span class="actionname">DummyAction2</span>
        <div class="actionOptions">
            <span class="optionname">Option1</span>
            <select class="ddl" id="Option1">
                <option value="D">D</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="actionOptions">
            <span class="optionname">Option2</span>
            <span class="spantxtbox">
                <input name="text" class="txtbox" id="Option2" type="text">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action DummyAction3" id="20">
        <span class="actionname">DummyAction3</span>
        <span>Options:</span>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="actionOptions">
            <span class="optionname">Option1</span>
            <select class="ddl" id="Option1">
                <option value="AA">AA</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="actionOptions">
            <span class="optionname">Option2</span>
            <select class="ddl" id="Option2">
                <option value="DD">DD</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
    var ScenarioDef = {};               

               var steps = [];

               $(".action").each(function () {
                   var $this = $(this);

                   steps.push({Name : $this.find('.actionname').text()});

                   var RequestParams = {};

                   RequestParams.ActionName = $this.find('.actionname').text()                      
                   steps.push(RequestParams);

                   var ActionOptions = [];
                   $this.find(".actionOptions").each(function () {

                       var $this1 = $(this);
                       if ($('.ddl').length) {
                           ActionOptions.push({
                               key: $this1.find('.optionname').text(),
                               value: $this1.find('.ddl :selected').text()
                           });
                       } else {
                           ActionOptions.push({
                               key: $this1.find('.optionname').text(),
                               value: $this1.find('.txtbox').text()
                           });
                       }

                   });
                   RequestParams.ActionOptions = ActionOptions;


               });

               ScenarioDef.steps = steps;
```

Expected JSON format.

```
{

    "ScenarioDef": {
        "steps": [
            {
                "Name": "DummyAction2",
                "RequestParams": {
                    "ActionName": "DummyAction3",
                    "ActionOptions": [
                        { "key": "Option1", "value": "AA" },
                        { "key": "Option2", "value": "DD" },
                        { "key": "Option3", "value": "" }
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                "Name": "DummyAction3",
                "RequestParams": {
                    "ActionName": "DummyAction3",
                    "ActionOptions": [
                        { "key": "Option1", "value": "AA" },
                        { "key": "Option2", "value": "DD" },
                        { "key": "Option3", "value": "" }
                    ]
                }
            }
                ]
            }
    }
```

I'm getting below output:

```
"ScenarioDef": {
    "steps": [
        { "Name": "DummyAction2" },
        {
            "ActionName": "DummyAction2",
            "ActionOptions": [ { "key": "Option1", "value": "D" },
                                { "key": "Option2", "value": "" } ]
        },
        { "Name": "DummyAction3" },
        {
            "ActionName": "DummyAction3",
            "ActionOptions": [
                { "key": "Option1", "value": "AA" },
                { "key": "Option2", "value": "DD" },
                { "key": "Option3", "value": "" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this purely an academic exercise?

Comment: It is not exercise... In our project we are using 100% JQuery & AngularJS in client side.

Comment: Normally you use a angularjs template to turn json into HTML. Why on earth would you want to do the reverse?!

Comment: I'm saving my data, we are using POST[REST API service] method here.

Comment: Render your data using angularjs templating and use the built in two way data binding to update your json object. Then send that to your endpoint. This is literally the most wrong possible way to use Angularjs (or any JS framework)

Comment: Here I've to use JQuery for creating JSON Object. Did you see any issue in my Jquery code.

Comment: This is a lot of code to look through and digest to be able to answer your question.   It would be helpful to pare this down to a more minimal example that still demonstrates the problem.   I'm thinking 10 to 20 lines of code, input, and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect answer.

below code will help you getting you want.

But this answer is perfectly clear. Maybe has some bugs.

If you get correct answer, run more JQuery's **each** and **selector**

```
//var ScenarioDef = [];
var ScenarioDef = {};

// $("#addconfigurations .action").each(function () {
$(".action").each(function () {
    // var steps = [];
    var steps = {};
    // steps.push({Name: $('.actionname1').text()});
    steps.Nmae = $('.actionname').text()

    //ScenarioDef.push(steps);
    ScenarioDef.steps=steps;

    //var RequestParams = [];
    var RequestParams = {};
    //RequestParams.push({ActionName: $('.actionname1').text()});
    RequestParams.ActionName= $('.actionname').text()


    //steps.push(RequestParams);
    steps.RequestParams = RequestParams;

    var ActionOptions = [];    
    $(".actionOptions").each(function () {
        // move to out of each
        //var ActionOptions = [];
        // IS NEW!!!
        var $this  = $(this);
        if ($('.ddl').length) {
            ActionOptions.push({
                //key: $('.optionname').text(),
                key: $this.find('.optionname').text(),
                //value: $('.ddl :selected').text()
                value: $this.find('.ddl :selected').text()
            });
        } else {
            ActionOptions.push({
                //key: $('.optionname').text(),
                key: $this.find('.optionname').text(),
                //value: $('.txtbox').text()
                value: $this.find('.txtbox').text()
            });
        }
        //RequestParams.push(ActionOptions);

    });
    RequestParams.ActionOptions = ActionOptions;

    console.log(ScenarioDef);

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(ScenarioDef);
    console.log(myJsonString);
});
```

Your answer's problem is knowledge of object and array.

Object {}

Object has key,value pair which is separated by colon :

```
{name:'Jone', age:'7'}
```

Array []

Array has only value which is separated by comma ,

```
['Jone', 'Jane', 'Lora']
```

But array's value type can accept Object

```
[{name:'Jone', age:'7'}
,{name:'Jane', age:'8'}
,{name:'Lora', age:'9'}]
```

You must need understand this difference with Object and Array.

This is very important for programmer, to create data structure.

Comment: {"steps":{"Name":"DA3","RequestParams":[{"ActionName":"Dn3"},
[{"key":"O1","value":"A"}],
[{"key":"O2","value":"D"}],
[{"key":"On3","value":""}]
]}}    I NEED   "RequestParams": {
                        "AName": "A1",
                        "AOptions": [
                        {
                            "key": "O1",
                            "value": "V1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "O2",
                            "value": "V2"
                        }
                        ]                        
                    }

Comment: No one will ever want to maintain this code. You should never parse HTML into JSON. The layout of your HTML should never make a difference in your JSON data structures. This is the most fragile code in existence.